# Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 42.1021.1 failing to install for android

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi I've trying to install Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging for notifications and I have been pulling my hair out for the past 3 days and I keep getting this error:

```
This collection is read-only
```

among many other from the different approaches I've tried like

- Uninstalling Xamarin.GooglePlayServices packages and installing 
  Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging without any of the other
  Xamarin.GooglePlayServices packages installed.
- Changing The Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging To a different package version
- Updating my AppCompat package(and even this fails to install)

As well as some other approaches that I can't re-call or clearly state right now. Luckily I've been using a Dummy project because had I not been doing so my project would have been broken or corrupt by now. Here's the nuget  package installation [log](https://pastebin.com/tsjU0vaT). Please assist I would highly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried to delete Xamarin.GooglePlayServices folders in the "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin" path?

Comment: No I haven't tried that as yet @hichame.yessou but I'll have a crack at it and let you know how it goes

Comment: @hichame.yessou first of all sorry for taking so long to reply. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work